# Segurança de web api: SSL?

Tags: c#, segurança, asp.net-web-api, ssl

Gostaria de saber se tem como restringir as requisições à uma web api especificamente para uma máquina.

Minha web api ficará hospedada no computador A.

Meu cliente (a princípio somente um) ficará hospedada no computador **B**.

Servidores diferentes, máquinas diferentes.

Tem como eu filtrar que a web api só "responda" ao cliente do computador **B**?

1. Seria por SSL? Como funciona? Basta só instalar o certificado no servidor e no cliente? Eu preciso tratar a requisição do lado do servidor?
2. É bem provável de no futuro ter um aplicativo mobile para consultar a mesma web api.. Como agir no caso de "liberar" as requisições do aplicativo?

Comment: @Downvoter: Favor comentar o que pode ser melhorado na pergunta, ou indicar o que tem de errado nela para eu poder corrigir.

Comment: Veja se [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582396/how-to-use-a-client-certificate-to-authenticate-and-authorize-in-a-web-api) ajuda. Tem um [post do blog do Carlos Figueira no MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/03/09/implementing-requirehttps-with-asp-net-web-api/) que explica como filtrar chamadas usando um certificado. Acredito que para filtrar, o correto é ter um certificado mesmo, e filtar as chamadas para permitir somente as chamadas que tiverem este certificado.

Comment: SSL serve para criptografar a conversa entre um cliente e um servidor de forma a evitar interceptação dos dados por terceiros, bem como garantir ao cliente que o servidor é dono da metade privada do par de chaves. Seu  objetivo é garantir a confiabilidade e a privacidade da informação trafegada, não a restrição de acesso. Isso pode ser obtido através de firewalls, configurações no servidor HTTP ou, de forma ideal, com métodos de autenticação como descrito nas respostas abaixo. Pode-se usar autenticação por certificado digital ("assinatura eletrônica"), mas isso não é o mesmo que SSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você precisa implementar é autenticação, principalmente porque você falou que no segundo momento você vai ter um aplicativo mobile.

Com o app mobile você não vai ter mais o controle de quem é a origem da aplicação. Se não tivesse um aplicativo mobile, talvez você poderia fazer a restrição pelo IIS já que o domínio de origem é conhecido e único.

Use alguma das versões de autenticação oAuth, a versão 1.0 é bem simples e rápido de implementar.

SSL não te ajuda em nada nesse cenário.

Comment: Entendo que a autenticação seja uma boa sugestão. Entretanto entendo que a requisição pode ser interceptada, por exemplo. Um sujeito malicioso pode fazer isso e conseguir os dados de login, certo? Nunca usei o oAuth, não sei se ele trabalha dessa forma mas imagino que sim.. O que você sugere para evitar isso? Uma camada de segurança não resolve?

Comment: Você vai usar SSL também, justamente para não ser interceptado. Meu ponto é que SSL sozinho não resolve seu problema, mas sim authenticação + SSL.

Comment: Rapaz...pela sua resposta deu a entender que, para o meu caso, SSL e "nada" seria a mesma coisa. Por isso estranhei um pouco rsrs.. Se puder dar uma revisada na resposta e dar alguns exemplos.. vai ajudar muita gente com o conteúdo :)

Answer (score 0):

1 - SSL é o mínimo que você deve ter se pretende expor uma api para um cliente, mas isso não tem muita relação com seu problema.

2 - Enquanto você não tem um mobile app consumindo sua api, você tem algumas formas de restringir o acesso de seus clientes através de IPs [configurando o IIS](https://educoutinho.com.br/iis/como-bloquear-ou-liberar-acesso-de-um-site-por-ip-no-iis-7/), através de um Firewall ou até mesmo através um certificado digital para estabelecer a comunicação com sua api.

3 - Quando se tem um aplicação mobile consumindo uma api o cenário muda, não existe a possíbilidade de restrição por IP. Um dos padrões de autenticação utilizados nesse caso é o OAuth2:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183421/Simple-OAuth-Authorization-Server-with-Identity-Se
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth
- http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Answer (score 0):

> Gostaria de saber se tem como restringir as requisições à uma web api
>   especificamente para uma máquina

Resposta: Token por usuario

Minha recomendacao: jwtSecurityTokenHandler,

E para ter controle total voce precisa criar um filtro `AuthorizeAttribute` para determinado usuario.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MaquinaA")]
```